# Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: android, dart, flutter

My App can authenticate successfully when debugging against the Android emulator, but if I try to authenticate using debugging against the physical device (with same OS version), an error message appears after more than one minute waiting:

> Exception has occurred.
>
> _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

The error message points to the following code:

```
        if (responseJson[AuthUtils.authTokenKey] != null) {
          AuthUtils.insertDetails(
              userNameController.text, passwordController.text, responseJson);
...
        } else {
...
        };
```

And in the DEBUG CONSOLE I get the following:

> I/flutter ( 9531): Auth: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed
> out, errno = 110, address = example.com, port = 38975
> V/InputMethodManager( 9531): Starting input:
> tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4aece4e nm :
> example.com.todoapp ic=null

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `responseJson` seems to be inferred as type `List` and expects an integer in the index accessor `responseJson[intIndexhere]`, but `AuthUtils.authTokenKey` is a `String` which is not supported here. That would only be supported if `responseJson` would be a `Map`

Answer (score 20):

For my case
responseJson was of dynamic data type what i did  was to cast it to string.

change this

> responseJson[AuthUtils.authTokenKey]

to this

```
String jsonsDataString = responseJson.toString();
final jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);

//then you can get your values from the map
if(jsonData[AuthUtils.authTokenKey] != null){
...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. I was doing this in flutter.

```
  http.Response S=await 
  http.get("Your link here");
  String responseBody = S.body;
  dynamic jsonObject = jsonDecode(jsonDecode(S.body));
  print(jsonObject[0]["product_id"]);
  setState(() {
    data=jsonObject[0]["product_id"];
  });
```

Comment: You have to made Model of that Response String and use that value..

Comment: if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var responseString = response.body;
      print("responseString is $responseString");
      var valueMap = json.decode(responseString);
      print(valueMap);
      return WithdrawResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(valueMap));
    }else{
      return null;
    }

Answer (score 5):

I believe that in the line:

```
responseJson[AuthUtils.authTokenKey]
```

You're referencing an item in the list **responseJson** by the index **AuthUtils.authTokenKey**

And since **AuthUtils.authTokenKey** is a String, you cannot use it as in index of an array.

So you need first to get the index of **AuthUtils.authTokenKey** then use it to reference the item:

```
responseJson[responseJson.indexOf(AuthUtils.authTokenKey)]
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but instead getting the error message in the screenshot, I got the following: Could not load source 'dart:core/runtime/libstring_patch.dart': <source not available>.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I forgot to decode JSON, and that's why I was getting such error.

So don't forget to do like this before parsing it:

```
final result = json.decode(response.body);

result[AuthUtils.authTokenKey]
```

Comment: r u sure about this?

Comment: Same for me too.

Answer (score 3):

'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' **directly mean you are using String in place of Int** here: responseJson[AuthUtils.authTokenKey] takes an int as an index where 
 -> AuthUtils.authTokenKey is a  String . *

> Print your response.body in the console and check where is your
>   authTokenKey is stored.

*
**you can get its index directly by using indexOf in your response and use in response as an index to get authTokenKey**

Answer (score 3):

Got this error when testing a database in Firebase Firestore.

> The following assertion was thrown building
>   StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
>   _StreamBuilderBaseState>#52d4b): type 'String' is not a subtype
>   of type 'int'

The problem was my document field had a type of string, but it was expecting a number. So, changed from string to number and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue very similar to this. It was caused by a conditional assignment to a var that was causing the type to change at run time. Take a look at what NetworkUtil.authencateUser is returning. I bet it's a Future Try changing it to a Future>.

Do you have a different SHA1 key for your emulator? That could be the cause of the differences between the two environments.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the response is returning an **Array** of data.

```
{[{authTokenKey: 'asbc'}]}
```

In this case, you need to take the [0] element. Then you will get the Map in which you can access indexes with String values.

```
var authTokenElm = responseJson[0];
var authToken = authTokenElm[AuthUtils.authTokenKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_encode = json_encode($query_array);
$json_encode = str_replace("[", "", $json_encode);
$json_encode = str_replace("]", "", $json_encode);
echo $json_encode;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are making API post/put request please send a Map,

```
final payload = {data: [Array should be sent in this format]}
```

when you want to send Array of Map<String, dynamic> to the API body.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved just by changing the pdo_mysql to nd_pdo_mysql PHP extension.
[Changes in PHP Extension..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HInG7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).