# what should I do flutter. _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, phpmyadmin

Help me please, I really need help.
I don't know how to fix it.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uxAM.png)

[My php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CghRH.png)

Comment: If your jsondata is an array like `[1,2,3]`, you are not supposed to use a string like `'error'` as the index

Comment: Can you please provide your json output?

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This type mismatch error which means that you provide "String value " but needs of integer type value
for more information you refere this link [Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416469/type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int-of-index)