# flutter error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, jsonparser

I want to serialize data from json data using open api to Dart. However, the error continues, such as type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'. I need to return the string, but I think I'm trying to return the int type. But I don't know where the problem is.

Below is the code I wrote.

First, it is a file containing json data.
I thought there was a string-related error, so I assigned the variable type to Shop.fromJson as double.

```
class Shop {
  final String cmpnmNm;
  final double refineWgs84Lat;

  Shop({
    required this.cmpnmNm,
    required this.refineWgs84Lat,
  });

  Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
   : cmpnmNm=json["CMPNM_NM"] as String,
    refineWgs84Lat= json["REFINE_WGS84_LAT"] as double,
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CMPNM_NM": cmpnmNm,
    "REFINE_WGS84_LAT": refineWgs84Lat,
  };
}
```

The part where the list is generated in the form of List by invoking open api.

```
Future<List<Shop>> fetchshop() async{
  late List<Shop> shopList;
    String url = "my url code";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final responseBody = response.body;

  final jsonMap = json.decode(responseBody);

  shopList = jsonMap.containsKey("GGGOODINFLSTOREST")
      ? (jsonMap['GGGOODINFLSTOREST']['row'] as List)
      .map((e) => Shop.fromJson(e))
      .toList()
      : List.empty();

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    return shopList;
  }else{
    throw Exception('Failed to load shop info');
  }
}
```

The part of the main function that outputs api data.

```
class mapmain extends StatefulWidget {
 class _mapmainState extends State<mapmain> {
  late Future<List<Shop>> shops;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    shops = fetchshop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('가게 조회'),),
        body: Center(
         child: FutureBuilder<List<Shop>>(
           future: shops,
           builder: (context,snapshot){
             if(snapshot.hasData){
               return Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Text(snapshot.data?.length != 0
                       ? snapshot.data![0].cmpnmNm
                       : "없음"),
                   Text(snapshot.data?.length != 0
                       ? snapshot.data![0].refineWgs84Lat.toString()
                       : "-"),
                 ],
               );
             }
           },
         ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? And what does the json look like you are trying to parse?

Comment: Can you provide example json? Or particulary `json["CMPNM_NM"]`? What is the value?

Comment: can you add the json response as well?

Comment: This is an example of json.

{"GGGOODINFLSTOREST":[{"head":[{"list_total_count":1006},{"RESULT":{"CODE":"INFO-000","MESSAGE":"정상 처리되었습니다."}},{"api_version":"1.0"}]},{"row":[{"CMPNM_NM":"점심","INDUTYPE_NM":"식음료","SIGUN_NM":"포천시","BSN_TM_NM":"11:30~21:00","PROVSN_PRODLST_NM":"모든메뉴","BIZREGNO":"4431001715","PROVSN_TRGT_NM2":"결식아동","REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR":"경기도 포천시 선단동 53-1번지","REFINE_ZIPNO":"11161","REFINE_WGS84_LAT":"37.8541818220","REFINE_WGS84_LOGT":"127.1657763050","DETAIL_ADDR":"점심","PROVSN_TRGT_NM1":"동반1인","REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR":"경기도 포천시 건너말길 7"}]}]}

Comment: `responseBody` or `jsonMap` might not be in the type you want, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416469/type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int-of-index

Answer (score 1):

From the [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/language/operators#type-test-operators):

> Use the as operator to cast an object to a particular type if and only
> if you are sure that the object is of that type.

This means, that if you want to convert an `int` into a `double`, there is no problem in that, as both are subtypes of `num`. But in your example, given in the comments, we can clearly see that`REFINE_WGS84_LAT` is a `double` inside of a `String`

What this really means, is that `as` can only be used if two types are compatible, which is not the case for `String` and double, to fix the very error you are facing, you need to do the following:

```
class Shop {
  final String cmpnmNm;
  final double refineWgs84Lat;

  Shop({
    required this.cmpnmNm,
    required this.refineWgs84Lat,
  });

  Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
   : cmpnmNm=json["CMPNM_NM"],
    refineWgs84Lat=double.parse(json["REFINE_WGS84_LAT"]),
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CMPNM_NM": cmpnmNm,
    "REFINE_WGS84_LAT": refineWgs84Lat,
  };
}
```

But I higly suggest do use the package [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for making models as such.